# iOS 7 how to get current selected UITextField id

Tags: ios, iphone

When calling the dismissKeyboard, I added every UITextField to resignFirstResponder.

Is there a way I can get the id of currently selected UITextField and make it resignFirstResponder?

```
#import "NewBabyViewController.h"

@interface NewBabyViewController ()
@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UITextField *BabyName;
@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UITextField *BabyNickname;    
@end

@implementation NewBabyViewController

- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    UITapGestureRecognizer *tap = [[UITapGestureRecognizer alloc]
                                   initWithTarget:self
                                   action:@selector(dismissKeyboard)
                                   ];
    [self.view addGestureRecognizer:tap];
}

-(void)dismissKeyboard{

    [self.view endEditing:YES];
    //[self.BabyName resignFirstResponder];
    //[self.BabyNickname resignFirstResponder];
}

-(IBAction)textFieldDone:(id)sender
{
    [sender resignFirstResponder];
}

@end
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The solution to this problem isn't exactly obvious, but it is actually remarkably easy to solve. Simply use the following:

```
-(void)dismissKeyboard {
    [self.view endEditing:YES];
}
```

Comment: This is actually quite cool, but I don't think it removes first responder from a `contentEditable` web view (or the internal subview that is the first responder). :(

Comment: This is really nice. Prior to now I would walk through all the subviews to find the UITextField that is first responder so I can tell it to resign. :).

Comment: @0x7fffffff Thanks a lot. That's just what I was trying to find. I edited above sample code based on your answer.

Answer (score 2):

You should track the first responder yourself. There are multiple ways of doing that, but the simplest one is updating on `textFieldDidBeginEditing:`.

If you wish to thread into gray area, there is a private API method on both `UIApplication` and `UIWindow`, `- (id)firstResponder` which will give you the current first responder. I've had a good record with them. I prefer the `UIWindow` method, which is safer when multiple windows are involved.

Another way:

```
[[UIApplication sharedApplication] sendAction:@selector(resignFirstResponder) to:nil from:nil forEvent:nil];
```

Comment: I like the sendAction:to:nil trick. Use the responder chain to deliver a resign message to the first object in the chain. Clever. (voted)